# Webpack JS libraries or include via script tag?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, webpack

I am working on building a thin client and one of the tools I am trying to familiarise myself with is Webpack. In my research I have come across programmers that are including JQuery and/or Angularjs in their Webpack. Why would you want to do this as opposed to just including them via script tags on the page?

Comment: It makes building and deployment easier

Answer (score 0):

You include all of your own code plus the dependencies on which it relies in your webpack project, because it makes sure that all your dependencies are always loaded, and that you don't have to include a list of files along with your webpack file. Webpack essentially compiles your whole project in to one single file which makes your life easier during updating and releasing.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that if you are using something like Webpack, then you are also using a package manager. If you are, then you are referencing all your third party libraries through a package configuration file.

At the point of using webpack, this can then just read the configuration file, then bundle everything up for you, without any requirement for separate references.

The advantage of this is that you have bundled and minified code for all your references, you have greater control over versioning, and it is very easy to manage updates. Not only this, but if you are making use of a repository, then you only need to include your package configuration file in the repository and let the package manager handle downloading the correct files.